# Flutter remove null values from list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, option-type, dart-null-safety

I have a `List` of **optional** `DateTimes`. So the List can actually have `null` values inside. But now I need to remove all these `null`-values, to get a `List<DateTime`, instead of a `List<DateTime?>`. How is that possible?

I tried it like this:

```
    List<DateTime> timesOfDayNotNull = timesOfDay.where((time) => time != null).toList();
```

But this is giving me:

> A value of type 'List<DateTime?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do `List<DateTime> timesOfDayNotNull = List.from(timesOfDay.where((time) => time != null));`

Comment: @ChristopherMoore `The argument type 'Iterable<DateTime?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DateTime>'.The argument type 'Iterable<DateTime?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DateTime>'.`

Comment: Sorry see my edit. Should be `from` not `of` since `of` keeps type info.

Comment: this is giving me: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'function result'` at Runtime

Comment: That seems like an unrelated problem. There are no strings involved here. Check the stacktrace and do some debugging.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore this exact function is failing. The one you suggested :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231952/discussion-between-chris-and-christopher-moore).

Comment: Just `cast` the result: `timesOfDay.where((time) => time != null).toList().cast<DateTime>();`